# Asset Pipeline simple images do not work in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have an image: `sample.png`. I have verified it is a good image.

I put it in `app/assets/images`.

I reference it in the view with:

```
image_tag "sample.png"
```

It just refuses to work. So I created a new directory `public/assets/images`.

Still doesn't work.

This is needlessly complex. How can I actually see an actual image in my view?

Please note that I have read all of the Asset Pipeline documentation already.

The URL that is being generated is:

```
/images/sample.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `image_tag "sample.png"` returns a link like

```
<img alt="Sample" src="/assets/sample.png">
```

I think your are running your app in a production mode, you need to compile your assets with

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

after this command , the image will generate in `ROOT_PATH/public/assets/sample.png`

hope it works :)

Comment: I'm definitely running it in development mode. The url being generated is: ```/images/sample.png```.